# Scraping information from a web-based PDF using R

Tags: linux, r, pdf, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape text information from the following web-based PDF: http://www.cmegroup.com/delivery_reports/IssuesAndStopsReport.pdf

Any advice on how to do this? I have explored the tm package without much luck (doesn't recognize path):

```
> pdf.loader <- readPDF(control= list(text = "-layout"))
> rr <- pdf.loader(elem=list(uri="http://www.cmegroup.com/delivery_reports/IssuesAndStopsReport.pdf"),language="en",id="id1")
Error: Cannot handle URI 'http://www.cmegroup.com/delivery_reports/IssuesAndStopsReport.pdf'.
Error: Cannot handle URI 'http://www.cmegroup.com/delivery_reports/IssuesAndStopsReport.pdf'.
Warning messages:
1: In normalizePath(file) :
  path[1]="http://www.cmegroup.com/delivery_reports/IssuesAndStopsReport.pdf": No such file or directory
2: running command ''pdftotext' -layout 'http://www.cmegroup.com/delivery_reports/IssuesAndStopsReport.pdf' -' had status 1
```

I have also tried entering different "engine" arguments into `readPDF()` but with no luck.

Comment: If you are on linux you can use pdftotext command line utility instead.

Comment: Good thinking, but entering `pdftotext http://www.cmegroup.com/delivery_reports/IssuesAndStopsReport.pdf` gives the same "Cannot handle URI" error.

Comment: you can download the file with `download.file` and remove it afterwards. I assume it'll be slower if you are handling too many pdfs though

Comment: Yeah that should work fine, only four PDFs. Was hoping for a more direct solution, but this works for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following code :

```
library(pdftools)
pdf_text('http://www.cmegroup.com/delivery_reports/IssuesAndStopsReport.pdf')

[1] "                           CME CLEARING - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE\nDLV600-T\nBUSINESS DATE:      09/23/2022      DAILY ISSUES AND STOPS                 RUN DATE:   09/23/2022\nPRODUCT GROUP: FINANCIAL                                                   RUN TIME:   08:30:43PM\n\n\n\n            CONTRACT: SEPTEMBER 2022 30 YR U.S. TREASURY BOND FUTURES\n          SETTLEMENT: 130.218750000 USD\n NEXT AVAILABLE DATE: 08/26/2022\n         INTENT DATE:                       DELIVERY DATE:\n\nFIRM NBR ORIG FIRM NAME                                    ISSUED      STOPPED\n______________________________________________________________________________\n______________________________________________________________________________\n\n                            TOTAL:                               0           0\n                    MONTH TO DATE:                                       4,671\n\n            CONTRACT: SEPTEMBER 2022 10Y TREASURY NOTE FUTURES\n          SETTLEMENT: 113.625000000 USD\n NEXT AVAILABLE DATE: 09/20/2022\n         INTENT DATE:                       DELIVERY DATE:\n\nFIRM NBR ORIG FIRM NAME                                    ISSUED      STOPPED\n______________________________________________________________________________\n______________________________________________________________________________\n\n                            TOTAL:                               0           0\n                    MONTH TO DATE:                                      17,671\n\n            CONTRACT: SEPTEMBER 2022 5 YR TREASURY NOTE FUTURES\n          SETTLEMENT: 107.789062500 USD\n NEXT AVAILABLE DATE: 09/01/2022\n         INTENT DATE: 09/23/2022                      DELIVERY DATE: 09/27/2022\n\nFIRM NBR ORIG FIRM NAME                                    ISSUED      STOPPED\n______________________________________________________________________________\n660      CUST JP MORGAN                                                    500\n825      CUST PTG DIV SGAS                                    500\n______________________________________________________________________________\n\n                            TOTAL:                            500          500\n                    MONTH TO DATE:                                      28,664\n\n            CONTRACT: SEPTEMBER 2022 2 YEAR TREASURY NOTE FUTURES\n          SETTLEMENT: 102.855468750 USD\n NEXT AVAILABLE DATE: 08/26/2022\n         INTENT DATE:                       DELIVERY DATE:\n\nFIRM NBR ORIG FIRM NAME                                    ISSUED      STOPPED\n______________________________________________________________________________\n______________________________________________________________________________\n"
[2] "                           CME CLEARING - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE\nDLV600-T\nBUSINESS DATE:      09/23/2022      DAILY ISSUES AND STOPS                   RUN DATE:   09/23/2022\nPRODUCT GROUP: FINANCIAL                                                     RUN TIME:   08:30:43PM\n\n\n                            TOTAL:                                0            0\n                    MONTH TO DATE:                                        14,954\n\n            CONTRACT: SEPTEMBER 2022 3 YEAR TREASURY NOTE FUTURE\n          SETTLEMENT: 104.578125000 USD\n NEXT AVAILABLE DATE: 09/23/2022\n         INTENT DATE: 09/23/2022                      DELIVERY DATE: 09/27/2022\n\nFIRM NBR ORIG FIRM NAME                                    ISSUED      STOPPED\n______________________________________________________________________________\n617      HOUS MORGAN STANLEY                                                 1\n709      CUST BARCLAYS                                                      95\n825      CUST PTG DIV SGAS                                    656          560\n______________________________________________________________________________\n\n                            TOTAL:                            656            656\n                    MONTH TO DATE:                                           656\n\n            CONTRACT: SEPTEMBER 2022 ULTRA 10-YEAR U S TREASURY NOTE FUT\n          SETTLEMENT: 121.437500000 USD\n NEXT AVAILABLE DATE: 09/20/2022\n         INTENT DATE:                       DELIVERY DATE:\n\nFIRM NBR ORIG FIRM NAME                                    ISSUED      STOPPED\n______________________________________________________________________________\n______________________________________________________________________________\n\n                            TOTAL:                                0            0\n                    MONTH TO DATE:                                        43,088\n\n            CONTRACT: SEPTEMBER 2022 20-YEAR U.S. TREASURY BOND    FUTURES\n          SETTLEMENT: 133.281250000 USD\n NEXT AVAILABLE DATE: 08/25/2022\n         INTENT DATE:                       DELIVERY DATE:\n\nFIRM NBR ORIG FIRM NAME                                    ISSUED      STOPPED\n______________________________________________________________________________\n______________________________________________________________________________\n\n                            TOTAL:                                0            0\n                    MONTH TO DATE:                                            17\n"                                                                                                                                                             
[3] "                           CME CLEARING - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE\nDLV600-T\nBUSINESS DATE:      09/23/2022      DAILY ISSUES AND STOPS                 RUN DATE:   09/23/2022\nPRODUCT GROUP: FINANCIAL                                                   RUN TIME:   08:30:43PM\n\n            CONTRACT: SEPTEMBER 2022 LONG TERM U.S. TREASURY BOND FUTURE\n          SETTLEMENT: 142.750000000 USD\n NEXT AVAILABLE DATE: 09/09/2022\n         INTENT DATE:                       DELIVERY DATE:\n\nFIRM NBR ORIG FIRM NAME                                    ISSUED      STOPPED\n______________________________________________________________________________\n______________________________________________________________________________\n\n                            TOTAL:                              0            0\n                    MONTH TO DATE:                                      10,416\n\n\n\n                                     <<< End of Report >>>\n"
```